# taskgated no signature for pid

Tags: c++, macos, launchd

I'm trying to install a self-made LaunchDaemon in OS X 10.10, however, i run into some strange errors and can't find the solution.. hopefully someone knows the answer, I'm googleing my ass of for this..

basically, i have a simple program (written in C++), installed in /Library/Application Support/myfolder/myprogram. I set permission as follows:

```
chown root /Application Support/myfolder/myprogram
chmod 644 /Application Support/myfolder/myprogram
```

I got the .plist for the LaunchDaemons folder installed correctly (I'm sure about this).

Now when I boot up my Computer, I find this in my Logs (looping):

```
taskgated: no signature for pid=xxx (cannot make code: UNIX[no such process])
com.apple.xpc.launchd: (my.launchdaemons.plist) Service exited duo to signal: Killed: 9
com.apple.xpc.launchd: (my.launchdaemons.plist) Service ran only for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Okay, this seems like taskgated daemon thinks that my program is "insecure" thus blocking it from execution. Guessing this is based on signature checking, i did not sign my program.. and I don't want to do it.

So I tried to disable that check by modifying the taskgated.plist to add the -p argument when taskgated is started up, but that did not do the trick, still getting the same error.

Then I tried to disable signature checking system wide (I know this is a big security risk, but this was only for testing purpose) by using:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

But guess what: Still getting the same error (even after a reboot).
Simply killing taskgated does also not help (your not able to start any program, except using the ones that where open before killing taskgated).

So, is there SOME way to get around this annoying signature check or some other way to actually get my program running?

On the Mac i compiled the program (its not the same computer where I'm trying to install it) it is just running fine. I mean, i can run my program from terminal like:

```
bash$> ./myprogram
<output>
bash$>
```

but on the computer i want to install it on i get this:

```
bash$> ./myprogram
Killed: 9
bash$>
```

Just moved the program via USB Stick from one Computer to the other... I can't get the point... :/